# How to filter "show tables"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to filter the output of `show tables`.
The documentation has [one example](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-persisted-results.html) on how to do this using `result_scan(last_query_id())`, but for me the example does not work:

```
show tables;
select  "schema_name", "name" as "table_name", "rows"
    from table(result_scan(last_query_id()))
    where "rows" = 0;
-- SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 8 invalid identifier 'SCHEMA_NAME'
```

The column `SCHEMA_NAME` is actually in the output of `show tables`,
so I do not understand what is wrong.

Best,

Davide

Comment: Your code works for me.  Are you always running these two statements consecutively?

Comment: Can you share where your account is located (AWS-West, for example)?  The query above should work for you, as it is for others, but perhaps there is an issue that needs to be reported to Snowflake Support.

Comment: @waldente yes, I am running the two statements consecutively.
@MikeWalton, the account is located in `us-east-1`. Your solution to set `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE = False;` worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following on your account and see what it is set to:

```
show parameters like 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE';
```

If this is set to TRUE, then it is ignoring the quotes in your query, which will then uppercase the column names, which won't match to the lowercase names of the SHOW output.

To resolve for your own session, you can run the following:

```
ALTER SESSION SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE = False;
```

You can also change this at a user or account level, if you wish.  Setting this value to TRUE isn't recommended for the reason that you are running into.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the filter column using `$<col_n>` syntax (#8 for rows).

Example:

```
show tables;
select *
from table(result_scan())
where $8 > 5
```

That being said, your query worked for me.